# nested if statement vs && operator javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I've been converting some of my code from nested if statements by using the && operator, one of these nested statements works in it's old form, but once converted ceases to function.

Am I doing it wrong?

Consider:

```
;(function( $, window ){
    var jsonData = <venda_block></venda_block>,

    isActive = jsonData.isActive, // false = off, true = on
    spendThreshold = jsonData.spendThreshold,
    displayThreshold = jsonData.displayThreshold,
    orderTotal = <venda_total>,
    remainingSpend = spendThreshold - orderTotal;

    $('.deliveryType').text(jsonData.deliveryType);

    if (isActive) {
    if (orderTotal >= displayThreshold) {
    if (!(orderTotal >= spendThreshold)) {
        $('.freeDeliveryBlurb2').show();
        $('.remainingSpend').html(remainingSpend);
    }}}
    }( jQuery, window ));
```

&&

```
if (isActive) {
    if (orderTotal >= displayThreshold && !(orderTotal >= spendThreshold)) {
        $('.freeDeliveryBlurb2').show();
        $('.remainingSpend').html(remainingSpend);
    }}
    }( jQuery, window ));
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your first example (missing `)` ), but other than that, the statements appear equivalent to me.. under what conditions do you think it isn't working?

Comment: Yeah, it looks fine. I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dh2DB/3/) which performs ok.

Comment: Fixed the syntax error - this happened in transport.

Well, the .show(); function works on the first example, but not the second.  I can target my variables using a console in the first example, not the second.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can target my variables"?

Comment: Chrome, inspect element, open console.. type "orderTotal" or "displayThreshold" hit enter. 

If it returns undefined, probably a syntax error.  If it returns "38" or "40" respectively (for me) it's fine.

Comment: [How's this](http://jsfiddle.net/4dJCZ/21/)?

Comment: freedeliveryblurb2 is still showing, I want that hidden when isActive is set to "false" in my json..

Comment: I don't get how it's working for you D:  I replicate this code, and it doesn't work..

Comment: I'm lost. Did you want something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/4dJCZ/25/)?

Comment: Thank you all for help - finally got this sorted!

Because I was interogating the JSON from Venda Control Panel, I had to pass it in as a string with if (isActive === 'true') {

Thank again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the following if block with && :

```
if (isActive) {
if (orderTotal >= displayThreshold) {
if (!(orderTotal >= spendThreshold)) {
    $('.freeDeliveryBlurb2').show();
    $('.remainingSpend').html(remainingSpend);
}}}
```

The result could be like this :

```
if (isActive && orderTotal >= displayThreshold && !(orderTotal >= spendThreshold)) {
    $('.freeDeliveryBlurb2').show();
    $('.remainingSpend').html(remainingSpend);
}
```

Or, as !(orderTotal >= spendThreshold) is equivalent to (orderTotal < spendThreshold), be like this :

```
if (isActive && orderTotal >= displayThreshold && orderTotal < spendThreshold) {
    $('.freeDeliveryBlurb2').show();
    $('.remainingSpend').html(remainingSpend);
}
```

Be aware that there may be a bug in your original code as the below if statement is wrongly written :

```
if (orderTotal >= displayThreshold {
```

instead of

```
if (orderTotal >= displayThreshold) {
```

Comment: Thanks OOEngineer, I've since fixed the syntax error.  I'll try your suggestion and get back to you soon.  Wish me luck!

Comment: Also be aware that "}( jQuery, window ));" is not a part of the if block, it's the end of the body of the anonymous function "function( $, window )"